# Spring boot gateway role filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway, user-roles

I have a microservice project. I have 4 services. ServiceA 3001 port ServiceB 3002 port Gateway 3000 and user management port 3003
Now I sent a request to this service
When I do localhost:3000/a post method, I send the bearer token together. This service should respond because the person sending the request is admin. If the user sends it, it should not respond because it is not authorized.
I need to do these operations with gateway but I have no idea how to do it. If my project was a monolith project this is very simple. How can I do it in microservices? Which resources should I examine? Can you help me with this.